# Use power bank as a laptop battery

Tags: battery, asus-laptop

My Old ASUS laptop's battery is dead.So I want to take out all 1865 batteries and BMS and replace with power bank.The power bank capacity is 16000 mah and 18W PD support.Let me know can I turn it to laptop battery.

Comment: Make sure it physically fits, make sure the DC output voltage is correct, make sure the polarity is correct, and then try it. Likely it will not work because the Laptop will not recognize it.

Comment: The laptop will certainly not recognize it because laptop batteries aren't connected through USB.

Comment: Many laptops will simply decline to work if they don't have a working battery. Having power is not enough; they insist on having a battery.